# How to select boolean column based on the other column value in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, "relation", which store the relation between Rate and Deal.
It looks like:

```
DealId              RateId       IsPremium 
------------------------------------------------
    1                 A           True 
    2                 A           False           
    3                 B           False
    4                 B           True
    5                 B           True
    6                 C           False
    7                 C           False
```

DealId is unique, and one RateId can map to many different DealId.

Now, Buesiness team asked me to provide a report about this table, but **IsPremium** value will be changed to ***True*** if the same RateId in this table already has ***True*** value.

That means, based on the request, my new report will be:

```
DealId              RateId       IsPremium 
------------------------------------------------
    1                 A           True 
    2                 A           True           
    3                 B           True
    4                 B           True
    5                 B           True
    6                 C           False
    7                 C           False
```

Since RateId C doesn't have **True** value in the original table, I will keep showing it with False value.

I tried to use "Group BY RateId" in my SQL script, but can't deal with the value in IsPremium...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be

```
SELECT DealId, 
       RateId, 
       MAX(IsPremium) OVER (PARTITION BY RateId) AS IsPremium
FROM YourTable
```

[Online demo](http://rextester.com/YDARS62607)

(I'm assuming your column is `varchar` with strings "true" and "false" as SQL Server doesn't have Boolean columns. Similar will work for `bit` and 1/0 though)

```
SELECT DealId, 
       RateId, 
       CAST(MAX(CAST(IsPremium AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY RateId) AS BIT) AS IsPremium
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Solution of Martin work on SGBD with OLAP function (good idea Martin ;)  )


Solution 2:
select DealId, RateId, 
case when ispremium =1 then 1
when (select count(*) from  relation f2 where f1.dealid<>f2.dealid and f2.rateid=f1.rateid and ispremium=1)>0 then 1
else 0 end ispremium
from relation f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3:

```
with maxi as (
select RateId, 
max(cast(ispremium as integer)) ispremium
from test0713 f1
group by RateId
)
select f1.dealid, f2.* 
from test0713 f1 inner join maxi f2 on f1.RateId=f2.RateId
```